# Handling PHP response in swift

Tags: php, swift, xcode

I am new to swift and I have somehow managed to run some test programs. I have a working API for android which returns response in plain echo statements and it works just fine. Now I wish to use the same API for IOS but I get an error. 
Please help

My swift code

```
//converting resonse to NSDictionary
let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

    print(myJSON as Any)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

PHP code

```
echo ("SUCCESS"."HI THERE");
```

---

Everytime I run my swift code, I get the error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Most of the posts say that php response is not of correct JSON Format. But my existing APIs with same echo statements work well in android. One option is to rewrite APIs. But I am hoping there may be some workable solution.

Comment: BTW when I change PHP code to return a proper JSON response as name value pair - it works fine. I do not wish to do that because my android work is huge. A change would mean a lot of change on the other side too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON option to allow fragments not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599177/json-option-to-allow-fragments-not-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I assume 'data' is a string: '{"SUCCESS":"HI THERE"}'
  - so print that and make sure you are working with what you expect.   My data arrives from a CFStream inputStream but should be equivalent as it is from an ascii Linux box running sockets.   So, here's my code for latest Swift to convert from json:

```
let bytesRead = inStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
let bufferStr = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bytesRead!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
print("Stuff seems to have arrived: \(bufferStr)")
ProcessReceivedJsonData(dataReceived: bufferStr!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false)! as Data)
```

... then ...

```
func ProcessReceivedJsonData(dataReceived: Data) {
    do {
        let newDataReceived: Data = myDataReceived
        print(myDataReceived)
        if let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myDataReceived as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
// then I process the dictionary
```

I missed out the first bit in my answer - sorry for the oversight.

Comment: I added print(data as Any) just before deserialisation. I get same error with a line before as 'Optional(16 bytes)'

Comment: The solution that you gave didn't work cliff. I can see a response if I encode "hi there" in json as Json_encode("hi there").  I need to receive response without json_encode , like a normal input stream. can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you attach the relevant segments of your code.  I'll try testing it against my system.

Comment: Oh, and the PHP code that pushes the data on the stream.  Can you see the JSON-ified data before it leaves the PHP server so you know what you should be expecting at the Xcode end.

Comment: Oh, do me a favour, in Xcode, add a wee code snippet to JSON encode the data you expect to receive then run it through your code to make sure it behaves as expected.  Let's close the net on this.

Comment: I don't know what I did. But seems like it started working. Thanks cliff.               Can I have a combination of json and non json return from PHP and still handle both the responses.

Comment: That you'd have to play around with.   For what it takes, I just json all messages so I can best handle international code pages etc.  I guess you could parse them or attempt the de-json and catch errors.  Would it not be simpler to just wrap all of them?  My server code is python so it's easy.  I have not looked at PHP in this respect.

Comment: Thanks cliff. It was really helpful.